# From java object to xml object

Tags: java, xml, serialization, mapping, weblogic

I've created a web service client from a WSDL file with Axis. This webservice responses with an Axis object that I need to convert to com.bea.xml.XmlObjet. The reverse operation (XmlObject to Java Object) was easily made with Xpath (in weblogic workshop) and the setters of the object but I've been unsuccessfully trying to convert the response to an XmlObject.

I've been looking through the generated code for the client and in the java object there is a typeDesc that seems to be a mapping Xml-Java. I've also thought of getting a string from the object, concatenating the tags and the values of the getters... Is there any elegant way of doing this using the TypeDesc? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

how complex are Java Objects ?, have you looked at The Castor Project. maybe it can fix your needs.  http://www.castor.org/.